# Spring Boot load extra Controllers and Services from a jar inside external folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot Application with few Controllers, Services, Entities and Repositories, and I want to load at runtime some extra jars with Controllers, Services ecc. that I'll put in a directory, for example like this:

```
--MyFolder
     |
     SpringApp.jar
     PluginsFolder
        |
        Plugin1.jar
        Plugin2.jar
```

So while having SpringApp.jar as a base Spring Boot Application, is it possible to load some extra Controllers and so by simply putting jars in that folder? I don't care if it need to reboot, any help?

Answer (score 1):

**For adding controllers and services externally**:

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.path.to.class", "com.path.to.class"})`

**For adding Entity**:

`@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.path.to.class", "com.path.to.class"})`

**For adding Repositories**:

`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.path.to.class", "com.path.to.class"})`

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over these jars, I'll suggest to use custom spring boot starter in this way the jar autoconfigure itself and you don't need extra annotation.

[custom spring boot starter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter)